# SQL Query design across multiple normalized tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table relationship diagram:

[image: Table relationship diagram]

The base query is:

```
SELECT DateTime, SubgroupID, TestID 
FROM Subgroups 
WHERE CharID IN (SELECT CharID FROM CharList WHERE ChartType = 2) AND PtLoc > 0
```

I would then loop through the recordset to get the other info:

```
SELECT DefectDescription, Value 
FROM DefectDescriptions, DataValues 
WHERE SubgroupID = (SubgroupID from above) AND DefectID = SampleNumber
```

for each record above:

```
SELECT TextValue AS PartNum 
FROM ParameterEntries 
WHERE 
    TestID = (TestID from above) 
    AND ParameterID = (SELECT ParameterID FROM ParameterDefinitions WHERE ParameterName = "PartNum")

SELECT TextValue AS SerialNum  
FROM ParameterEntries 
WHERE 
    TestID = (TestID from above) 
    AND ParameterID = (SELECT ParameterID FROM ParameterDefinitions WHERE ParameterName = "SerialNum")
```

To build a table:

```
DateTime, PartNum, SerialNum, DefectDescription, Value(number of defects)
```

Can this be done in a single query instead of looping through each record to get the records from the linked tables?

Comment: You should really stop using syntax that was superseded some 28 years ago and start using the ANSI-92 sytle joins: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOIN](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you want to do.

Comment: At a first glance, it feels like a couple of CROSS APPLY s should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as one single query if you join the tables

```
SELECT
    Subgroups.DateTime, DefectDescriptions.DefectDescription, DataValues.Value,
    Subgroups.TestID, Count(*) AS NumberOfDefects,
    MAX((SELECT MAX(E.TextValue)
           FROM ParameterDefinitions AS D
           INNER JOIN ParameterEntries AS E ON D.ParameterID = E.ParameterID
           WHERE D.ParameterName="PartNum" AND E.TestID=Subgroups.TestID)
          ) AS PartNum,
    MAX((SELECT MAX(E.TextValue)
           FROM ParameterDefinitions AS D
           INNER JOIN ParameterEntries AS E ON D.ParameterID = E.ParameterID
           WHERE D.ParameterName="SerialNum" AND E.TestID=Subgroups.TestID)
          ) AS SerialNum
FROM
    DefectDescriptions
    INNER JOIN DataValues
        ON DefectDescriptions.DefectID = DataValues.SampleNumber
    INNER JOIN Subgroups
        ON DataValues.SubgroupID = Subgroups.SubgroupID
    INNER JOIN CharList
        ON CharList.CharID = Subgroups.CharID
WHERE
    CharList.CharType=2 AND Subgroups.PtLoc>0
GROUP BY
    Subgroups.DateTime, DefectDescriptions.DefectDescription,
    DataValues.Value, Subgroups.TestID;
```

If you copy/paste this into the query designer as SQL (in the SQL view), you will see how the tables are joined when switching back to the design view. The two parameters are selected with subqueries.

You also must use a GROUP BY clause to be able to count the number of defects with `Count(*)`

See also:

- [SQL Joins (w3schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)
- [SQL GROUP BY Statement (w3schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)
- [Subqueries (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: The count is already tallied in a single record in DataValues.Value.  So, that is not necessary.

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
'First' is not a recognized built-in function name.
This type of error is why I use the syntax I use.  This error is from SQL Server Management Studio 2016.  But, I have to have a syntax that is recognized in all versions of SQL Server from 2005, Oracle versions from 8, and Access 2002, And executed through ODBC and OLE-DB using all versions of the compatible drivers.  Using the fewest number of reserved words is the path of least resistance.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I think there is enough there to retool for my purposes.

Comment: Okay `First` is a function from Access. Use `MAX` instead. Note: there should be only one value, but otherwise you would have to put the subquery in the GROUP BY also. So I think it is better to use the MAX() aggregate function instead. I also refactored the FROM clause.